# Restricting number of charcters input to the UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a UITextField where in I am restricting entering more than 2 digits. Now, it works fine but when I tap on the text field & select all the content & then type it does not allow me to over-write the existing 2 digits.

Any clue on how to use 'selectedTextRange' property here?

```
- (BOOL)cell:(RunnerTableViewCell *)iCell shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)iRange replacementString:(NSString *)iString {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    NSCharacterSet *anUnacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    int aCharacterUpperLimit = 2;
    BOOL aReturnValue = YES;

    NSInteger aTotalLength = iCell.inputField.text.length + [iString length];
    NSLog(@"iString=%@ aTotalLength=%d",iString,aTotalLength);
    if ([[iString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:anUnacceptedInput] count] > 1 || (aTotalLength > aCharacterUpperLimit && ![iString isEqualToString:kRunnerEmptyString]) || [iString length] > aCharacterUpperLimit) {
        aReturnValue = NO;
    }
    return aReturnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSInteger aTotalLength = iCell.inputField.text.length + [iString length] - iRange.length;
```